# How to convert a graph into a table

Tags: r, data-visualization, tables, transform

I have seen lots of examples of how to create a table in `R` from a `data.frame`, but my question is how can I create a table from a graph output in `R`?

I am working with the package `AdehabitatHR`, and I have produced some graphs showing variation in area (metres) as a function of $k$.  Thus can someone tell me how to create a table from a (xy) line graph.

This is my script

```
#Read the data file
Ade <- read.csv("Ade.csv", header=TRUE, dec=",") 
data <-SpatialPointsDataFrame(Ade[,4:5],as.data.frame(Ade[,2])) 
#Check the data frame is correct
str(data)
head(data, 2)
# Examines the changes in home-range size for various values of k
LoCoH.k.area(data, krange=50:90, percent=95, unin = c("m"), unout = c("km2"),   
duplicates=c("random"), amount = NULL)
```

[image: LoCoH.k.area output graph]